# How to query a ranked leaderboard table for specific user entry and subset of entries "around" the user?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions, leaderboard

I have the following tables that make up a ranked leaderboard:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "username" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "leaderboard" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "leaderboard_entry" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "score" integer unsigned NOT NULL CHECK ("score" >= 0),
    "leaderboard_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "leaderboard" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE INDEX "score_idx" ON "leaderboard_entry" ("score" DESC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "leaderboard_id_user_id_idx" ON "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id");
CREATE INDEX "leaderboard_id_idx" ON "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id");
CREATE INDEX "user_id_idx" ON "leaderboard_entry" ("user_id");

-- Create a leaderboard
INSERT INTO "leaderboard" ("name") VALUES ('Global Leaderboard');

-- Create some users
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Extreme Hawk');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Screaming Whistler');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Crashing Underdog');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Burly Creature');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Snarky Acrobat');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Deadly Striker');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Dark Zebra');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Eager Raptor');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Snarky Leader');
INSERT INTO "user" ("username") VALUES ('Keen Joker');

-- Add some leaderboard entries with random scores
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 2, 80);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 3, 45);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 4, 55);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 5, 95);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 6, 90);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 7, 90);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 8, 25);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 9, 60);
INSERT INTO "leaderboard_entry" ("leaderboard_id", "user_id", "score") VALUES (1, 10, 55);
```

I can rank a specific leaderboard with this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT "leaderboard_entry"."id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."user_id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."score",
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "rank",
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "percentile_rank",
       "leaderboard"."id",
       "leaderboard"."name",
       "user"."id",
       "user"."username"
  FROM "leaderboard_entry"
 INNER JOIN "leaderboard"
    ON ("leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = "leaderboard"."id")
 INNER JOIN "user"
    ON ("leaderboard_entry"."user_id" = "user"."id")
 WHERE "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = 1
 ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC
```

This produces the correct results where every entry is properly ranked:

```
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+--------------------+
| Leaderboard ID |  Leaderboard Name  | Rank | Percentile | Score | User ID |     User Name      |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+--------------------+
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  1   |   0.000    |   95  |    5    |   Snarky Acrobat   |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  2   |   0.111    |   90  |    6    |   Deadly Striker   |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  2   |   0.111    |   90  |    7    |     Dark Zebra     |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  4   |   0.333    |   80  |    2    | Screaming Whistler |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  5   |   0.444    |   60  |    9    |   Snarky Leader    |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  6   |   0.556    |   55  |    4    |   Burly Creature   |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  6   |   0.556    |   55  |    10   |     Keen Joker     |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  8   |   0.778    |   45  |    3    | Crashing Underdog  |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  9   |   0.889    |   25  |    8    |    Eager Raptor    |
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  10  |   1.000    |   15  |    1    |    Extreme Hawk    |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

However, I am unable to query for a specific User ID in order to know their rank in the leaderboard.  It always says they're ranked 1.  I assume this is because the filter for User ID is being applied before the RANK() window function.  How can I do the query so that it returns the correct rank for a specific User ID?

This doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT "leaderboard_entry"."id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."user_id",
       "leaderboard_entry"."score",
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "rank",
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "percentile_rank",
       "leaderboard"."id",
       "leaderboard"."name",
       "user"."id",
       "user"."username"
  FROM "leaderboard_entry"
 INNER JOIN "leaderboard"
    ON ("leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = "leaderboard"."id")
 INNER JOIN "user"
    ON ("leaderboard_entry"."user_id" = "user"."id")
 WHERE ("leaderboard_entry"."user_id" = 3 AND "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = 1)
 ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC
```

```
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
| Leaderboard ID |  Leaderboard Name  | Rank | Percentile | Score | User ID |     User Name     |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
|       1        | Global Leaderboard |  1   |   0.000    |   45  |    3    | Crashing Underdog |
+----------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
```

The correct rank for User ID 3 should be 8, not 1.

Additionally, I would like to be able to filter for a specific User ID and return the entries "around" that user on the leaderboard.  So if a User is ranked 5, and I want to show the 4 entries around them, I would query for the User ID and also select the 2 rows ahead of them, and the 2 rows behind them.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running. Is this postgres?

Comment: @GMB These examples were produced with SQLite 3, but ultimately will be done in Postgres.  I would like to be database-agnostic.  I understand that may not be possible if PG-specific features are required to achieve the solution.

Comment: OK, I understand. The syntax of the above query should work on both Postgres and SQLite (same goes for the answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions operate on the resulting dataset, *after* filtering with the `where` predicates. So there is just one record left in the dataset after filtering, it will always be ranked first.

You would need to turn your existing query to a subquery, *then* filter on the given user:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT "leaderboard_entry"."id",
           "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id",
           "leaderboard_entry"."user_id",
           "leaderboard_entry"."score",
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "rank",
           PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" ORDER BY "leaderboard_entry"."score" DESC) AS "percentile_rank",
           "leaderboard"."id",
           "leaderboard"."name",
           "user"."id",
           "user"."username"
      FROM "leaderboard_entry"
     INNER JOIN "leaderboard"
        ON ("leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = "leaderboard"."id")
     INNER JOIN "user"
        ON ("leaderboard_entry"."user_id" = "user"."id")
     WHERE "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = 1
) t
WHERE "user_id" = 3
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause is not needed anymore, since the query returns just one row. Else, you would need to move it to the outer query too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery, with the window functions and then filter on the user in the outer query:

```
select . . . 
from (. . .
      where "leaderboard_entry"."leaderboard_id" = 1
     )
where "user_id" = 3
```